# trying to find out radious between two point but distance values remain same

Tags: java, android, graphics

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    switch(event.getAction())
    {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
    {
        cx=event.getX();
        cy=event.getY();
        Toast_Display.short_message(getContext(),"action down"+cx+" "+cy);
        return true;
    }
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
    {
        distance = Math.sqrt( Math.pow(cx-getX(),2)+Math.pow(cy-getY(),2));
        Toast_Display.short_message(getContext(),"action move"+cx+" "+cy+"  "+event.getX()+" "+event.getY());
        Toast_Display.short_message(getContext(),"action move"+distance);
        break;
    }

    default:
        return false;
    }
    invalidate();
    return true;
}
```

**Getting the same value for the distance at every calculation althoug the values of the points are changing. I think the problem is with the distance formula but don't know how to sort it out**

Comment: Where do you obtain the values of `cx, getX, cy, getY` from, when you're inside `ACTION_MOVE`?

Comment: cx and cy are declared globally but i was not geting the values of x and why with the reference to the event... they were supposed to get event.getX() and and event.getY()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess in the ACTION_MOVE you should use event.getX() instead of getX().